# Like freopen and scanf in c#

Tags: c#

There are `freopen` and `scanf` functions from c but for c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Filestream` and `Streamreader`.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
Console.SetIn(File.OpenText("file.txt"));
```

Source: [cyberforum](http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread1377030.html)
Could be helpful for people who stumble upon this question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`freopen` does not have a direct parallel. You'd have to `Close` and then re-create a `FileStream` object to get similar behavior.

`scanf` and similar type-unsafe functions have been replaced with `Parse` methods, e.g., `int.Parse`. Your `stdin` stream is `Console.In`. You'll have to do your own delimiting from the input stream into a string, which can then be parsed into an integer.

Comment: scanf is not for parse,
it to,
but its functionality is to read from stdin buffer

Comment: `scanf` does parsing from `stdin`. In .NET, you'll need to read from `Console.In` and *then* do parsing.

Answer (score -1):

I doit like this, as you say:

```
StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader("input.txt");

String readed = "";

while(readed != null){
    readed = objReader.ReadLine();  
    System.out.println(readed);
}
```

using StreamReader
then I can split it with ' ' to take each variable (in c will be scanf("%d%d%d",&v1,&v2,&v3))

thanks

Comment: @JohnSaunders  then how it should be more C#?

Answer (score -1):

I've just posted a `scanf()` replacement using C#. You can see and download the code at http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-sscanf-replacement-for-net.